# How to append the excerpt to the content in the single post page?

Tags: customization, loop, filters, hooks

For every Post, I have content and excerpt. I am trying to figure out how to include both of these in the single post page.

So far this is what I have:

```
function after_post_content($content){
if (is_single()) {  
    $content .= 'I need the excerpt to be displayed here.';
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "after_post_content" );
```

Any help in how to add the excerpt of the Post below the content of the Post will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
function after_post_content($content){
if (is_single()) {  
    $content .= the_excerpt();
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "after_post_content");
```

Comment: You should use `get_the_excerpt()` instead of `the_excerpt()`, since you are trying to return the value, not echo it.